# how M-M both active mysql replication handles unique key value

Tags: mysql, database-administration

How master-master both active mysql replication handles unique key value.
for primary key value we can set auto_increment_increment & auro_increment_offset parameter to avoid primary key auto_increment conflict.
But similarly how unique key constraints can be handled here ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: It *doesn't* handle them.

Because replication is asynchronous, you have a risk of causing [split-brain errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing)) if you write to both nodes of a master-master replication cluster concurrently. That is, you can insert successfully on both replication nodes, but when it comes time for the replica to replay the other's insert, it causes a conflict because the replica has already inserted a row with a conflicting value.

A similar problem can occur with foreign key constraints. For example, you could insert a row with an FK that references a parent row in another table, even though simultaneously someone has deleted that parent row in other node. When the two changes are replicated, it causes errors.

You can create the same effect if you have more complex constraints implemented in triggers. For example suppose you wrote a trigger that allowed you to delete rows from a table only if there were at least 5 rows left in the table. You delete a row, and the trigger allows it. But then the node replicates a delete from the other node, resulting in an invalid state of only 4 nodes left in the table.

Here are several ways you can prevent split-brain errors:

1. Allow writes only on one node, at least for the given table that has UNIQUE KEY or FOREIGN KEY or other constraints that will risk split-brain. This is the most common solution, generally making one of the nodes globally read-only (not just for one table, but for the whole instance).
2. Use some kind of global semaphore to "lock" access to a given table. The semaphore names which node allows writes to the table, and that must be obeyed by all apps connected to your replica-set. You can change the semaphore, but not until all changes made on one node have replicated to the other. But that works against the goal of allowing concurrent writes on multiple nodes.
3. Enforce synchronous replication. That is, you can't make any changes to a node while there are replication changes pending. Galera Cluster has a mode in which local changes on a node — and even SELECT statements — must wait until all pending binary logs have been played.
4. Make all writes asynchronous but ordered. Instead of writing directly to the database, write to a message queue, then make one back-end processor consume the queue in a serial order, applying changes. This can still result in errors, like the example of disallowing a DELETE from reducing the table to fewer than 5 rows. But at least it won't be a split-brain error.